# How to convert Custom Properties of old log4j.xml to new log4j2.xml

Tags: xml, log4j2

I am migrating old log4j.xml file to new log4j2.xml file and trying to convert the below snippet:

```
<appender name="LOGFILE" class="com.ubs.ef.logger.TimeSizeRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <param name="File" value="${logfile}"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="2000MB"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%-5p] [%r] %d [%X{truncatedThreadName}] %x %c{1}-%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

I converted to something like below, but its not working as expected.

```
<RollingFile name="fileLogger"
                    fileName="${basePath}/app.log"
                    filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
                    policy="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5p] [%r] %d [%X{truncatedThreadName}] %x %c{1}-%L - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2000MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by doing below:

```
<RollingFile name="fileLogger" 
                    fileName="logs/application.log"
                    filePattern="logs/application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i"
                    append="true">
```